# My TV keeps saying invalid format

Tags: windows-7

I connected my PC to my 40" LG TV and the starting screen came up but when it gets to the screen with the icons on the side it goes black and says invalid format.

Comment: What's the resolution and refresh set from your graphics card? The TV might not be able to support it.

Comment: How is the TV connected, is it HDMI, DVI or VGA?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a GPU vendor utility/control panel on the PC e.g. NVIDIA ,check for a 'auto monitor detection' (or similar) checkbox or radio button. Maybe even look for an option to output to digital television within the utility.

If integrated graphics is being used I guess look for an icon in the system tray such as 'Intel HD graphics'. Check settings in here.

If none of the above hit up Google for Windows 7's auto monitor detection settings. Although I believe it is more of a job to actually turn these off!

Also is there a setting on the TV itself such as or similar to 'HDMI auto detection'? If so this should be checked on.

Comment: This assumes an HDMI connection. Not stated by the OP

Answer (score 1):

there is a discussion on CNET - google "tv indicates invalid format" which is relative to the HDMI input and the resolution of the TV vs the input (your PC).
If your computer is outputting 1080p and the LG is looking for 720p that will give that error.